# Is sum or reduce(:+) better in Ruby/Rails? Are there considerations other than speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems like #sum is faster than #reduce for long arrays, and they are basically the same for short ones.

```
def reduce_t(s,f)
  start = Time.now
  puts (s..f).reduce(:+) #Printing the result just to make sure something is happening.
  finish = Time.now
  puts finish - start
end
def sum_t(s,f)
  start = Time.now
  puts (s..f).sum
  finish = Time.now
  puts finish - start
end

irb(main):078:0> sum_t(1,10); reduce_t(1,10)
55
0.000445
55
0.000195
=> nil
irb(main):079:0> sum_t(1,1000000); reduce_t(1,1000000)
500000500000
8.1e-05
500000500000
0.101487
=> nil
```

Are there considerations other than speed? Are there any situations when it would be better to use #reduce instead of #sum to accomplish the same end, a simple sum?

**Edit**

[mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) rightly pointed out that I should do numerous iterations before drawing conclusions about timing results. I didn't use `Benchmark` because I'm not familiar with it yet, but I hope what I've written below will be adequate and convincing.

```
def sum_reduce_t(s,f)
  time_reduce = 0
  time_sum = 0
  reduce_faster = 0
  sum_faster = 0
  30.times do
    start_reduce = Time.now
    (s..f).reduce(:+)
    finish_reduce = Time.now
    time_reduce += (finish_reduce - start_reduce)
    start_sum = Time.now
    (s..f).sum
    finish_sum = Time.now
    time_sum += (finish_sum - start_sum)
    if time_sum > time_reduce
      reduce_faster += 1
    else
      sum_faster += 1
    end
  end
  puts "Total time (s) spent on reduce: #{time_reduce}"
  puts "Total time (s) spent on sum: #{time_sum}"
  puts "Number of times reduce is faster: #{reduce_faster}"
  puts "Number of times sum is faster: #{sum_faster}"
end

irb(main):205:0> sum_reduce_t(1,10)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 0.00023900000000000004
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00015400000000000003
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
irb(main):206:0> sum_reduce_t(1,100)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 0.0011480000000000004
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00024999999999999995
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
irb(main):207:0> sum_reduce_t(1,1000)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 0.004804000000000001
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00019899999999999996
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
irb(main):208:0> sum_reduce_t(1,10000)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 0.031862
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00010299999999999996
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
irb(main):209:0> sum_reduce_t(1,100000)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 0.286317
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00013199999999999998
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
irb(main):210:0> sum_reduce_t(1,1000000)
Total time (s) spent on reduce: 2.7116779999999996
Total time (s) spent on sum: 0.00021200000000000008
Number of times reduce is faster: 0
Number of times sum is faster: 30
=> nil
```

My question remains: are there ever times when it makes sense to use #reduce instead of #sum?

Comment: where did you get `sum` from in Ruby?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it's in in ruby 2.4. Wohoo!

Comment: @Anthony oooh, didn't know that, I am still on 2.3 :)

Comment: (1) You need to do more than one iteration to get any useful timing results, maybe you should use `Benchmark` from the standard library instead of rolling your own. (2) Given that [`Array#sum` is directly implemented in C in MRI](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview2/array.c#L5682), it shouldn't be surprising that it is faster.

Comment: Hi @mu, I did numerous iterations and the results were consistent, but I should update the question with this. I've never tried Benchmark, so I will now.

Comment: @Anthony, that was supposed to be a surprise. Leo, you should add a Rail's tag, as Ruby v2.4.0 has not been released.

Comment: Well, if you want to sum the elements of `a=[1,2,3]` and add `4`, you could write `a.reduce(4,:+) #=> 10` rather than `4+a.sum`. I'm not sure if that's relevant to your question, however.

Comment: @Cary I will! I was confused by this. I was using irb for this all. So when I use irb, am I tapping into Rails somehow? `ruby -v` indicates that I am on ruby 2.2.3. Thank you for jumping in.

Comment: @Cary, is there an advantage to `a.reduce(4,:+) ` over `4+a.sum`? More elegant? Faster?

Comment: I mean... is this a problem?  This seems like a kind of pointless optimization to make; either one runs in linear time.

Comment: Leo, I'm on v2.3.0 and `[1,2,3].sum #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'sum' for [1, 2, 3]:Array`. I expect the difference in execution speed doesn't amount to a [hill of beans](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hill+of+beans). Which is more elegant? You tell me.

Comment: @Cary So I'm using rails; I have  arrays; and I want to find their sums. I've demonstrated that the sum method is measurably faster at doing this for long arrays. So it seems best to use sum. (Would you agree with that, or am I more confused than I know?) My question is, are tradeoffs or consequences of this decision that I may not be aware of? Perhaps the answer is simply, no. It's just  a red flag to me when there's a method that seems to do the same thing as another method, but worse. It makes me wonder whether the slow method serves some purpose or has some benefit that I don't see.

Comment: Also @Casey my last comment; it would only let me tag one of you at a time.

Comment: Leo, I'll certainly use `sum` over `reduce(:+)` when it becomes available, but everyone won't, in part because they need to have code that is compatible with earlier versions of Ruby. True, `sum` and `reduce(:+)` do the same, but you should see no red flag as `reduce` does far more.  By "tags" to your question, I see you added "ruby-on-rails" (unless it was there all the time).

Comment: Thank you @Cary, that makes sense. I did add ruby-on-rails tag, which is what I thought you recommended I do--right?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and use it.  But if you have some code using reduce, it's probably not worth going out of your way to change it.

Comment: I would like to add that 6.5 years later, I would like to go on the record stating that I no longer care about what is "elegant."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way that the behaviour and result of using `sum` differ from `inject &:+` is when you are summing floating point values.

If you add a large floating point value to a small one, often the result is just the same as the larger one:

```
> 99999999999999.98 + 0.001
=> 99999999999999.98
```

This can lead to errors when adding arrays of floats, as the smaller values are effectively lost, even if there is a lot of them.

For example:

```
> a = [99999999999999.98, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
=> [99999999999999.98, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
> a.inject(&:+)
=> 99999999999999.98
```

In this example, you could add `0.001` as often as you want, it would never change the value of the result.

[Ruby’s implementation of `sum`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview2/enum.c#L3633-L3656) uses the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) when summing floats to reduce this error:

```
> a.sum
=> 100000000000000.0
```

(Note the result here, you might be expecting something ending in `.99` as there are 10 `0.001` in the array. This is just normal floating point behaviour, perhaps I should have tried to find a better example. The important point is that the sum does increase as you add lots of small values, which doesn’t happen with `inject &:+`.)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Look at [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933431/5037635) answer. `sum` handles floats better.

---

OK, I think the comments can be combined to form a good answer, though I would certainly accept others if anyone wants to explain in more depth.

The key points are:

- The sum method is not available in current versions of Ruby, but is anticipated in the future. I was using it via Rails, where it is available.
- The sum method is indeed faster for summing huge arrays.
- It's probably not worth changing old code from reduce to sum, unless there are performance issues relating to extremely long arrays.
- "Given that Array#sum is [directly implemented in C in MRI](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview2/array.c#L5682), it shouldn't be surprising that it is faster." (mu is too short)
- Reduce does many other things (`reduce(:-)`, `reduce(:*)`, etc.), so it shouldn't be dismissed as useless. It's just not the best choice for summing a gigantic array if the sum method is available.
- The most important point, I think: If you need your code to be compatible with earlier versions of Ruby, reduce is safer.
- "Sum does increase as you add lots of small values, which doesn’t happen with inject &:+." (@matt)
- The reduce method can result in some fun emoticons.

The direct answers to my questions are:

- Are there considerations other than speed? **Yes** (compatibility, adding very large numbers to very small ones).
- Are there any situations when it would be better to use #reduce
  instead of #sum to accomplish the same end, a simple sum? **Yes**
  (compatibility).

Comment: Good summary! Could you also add @matt's explanation about sum's improved behavior for floating point?

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers and comments brings very good input, but I could not find anyone mentioning the effect on using the different methods on an empty array.

`sum` on an empty array results in `0` while `reduce(:+)` returns `nil`. This might be relevant for the use case of the two different methods. `0` and `nil` may mean different things here.
Using `reduce(:+)` on an array with zeroes, the result will be `0`.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> [].reduce(:+)
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> [].sum
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> [0].reduce(:+)
=> 0
```

Tested with both Ruby 3.1.1 and Rails 7.0.3.